# extracting string from files and merge (python)

Tags: python

I have a directory with multiple subfolders that all contain several text files which are formatted in the following way.

```
data01:data02
```

I need to extract just the data02 after the `:` and export this to a single file in the root directory. I got the extraction in place, but how can I run this on multiple directories and files?

Comment: Hi Gromit, this looks like a perfect task for command line tools "find" and "awk". Can you please explain, why you'd require python for this task?

Comment: If you have a suggestion resolve this just by using cmd, it's also a option I'am just not familiar with using awk etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the following command line with "find" and "awk"

```
find FOLDERLIST -type f -iname "PATTERN" \
     -exec awk -F":" 'NF>1 {print $2}' "{}" \; > /PATH/TO/RESULTFILE
```

where

- FOLDERLIST is a space separated list of top folders you want to recursively search, whereby the "current folder" would be a dot: find . -type f ...
- "-type f" for searching files only
- PATTERN is the common pattern of the files you are interested in, e.g. an asterix "*" will find all files, "*.csv" will find CSV files, ...
- /PATH/TO/RESULTFILE is the name of your result file in root directory
- the "awk" part splits all found files at the ":" and skips empty results

*EDIT: adjusted empty results check to NF>1 as suggested by steeldriver.*

Comment: `NF>1 {print $2}` might be safer (in case `$2` evaluates numerically as 0)

Comment: You are right steeldriver, thank you :)

Comment: No problem - upvoted ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided the format of the output file, so I am writing assuming that you want second field in separate line. You can use(assuming all files are in the format `a:b` as you said in your question):

```
find directory -type f \
-exec awk -F: '{print $2}' "{}" >> /output.txt \;
```

It will find files in `directory` and in it's sub-directory, and will execute command `awk -F: '{print $2}' "{}" >> /output.txt`, which will write value after `:`, to a file `/output.txt`.